# IE: how to trigger body's vertical scrollbar recalculation

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, scroll

I have a problem with a vertical scrollbar on a custom SharePoint list form in IE. After navigating to the add attachment window and returning back **the vertical scrollbar goes over the lower edge of the window** so that one cannot scroll to the very bottom of the form.

Resizing the window fixes this problem so probably if I could to somehow **force the window to recalculate the scrollbar from javascript** without resizing the window it would be an easy workaround.

Is it possible to trigger such 'resize' and how?

Any other solutions for this specific problem are welcome as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

browsers re calculate the body height and thus the scrollbar when the dom is manipulated.
tryinserting a blank div or spacer gif or something at the bottom...